Unchecked Input for Loop Condition CheckMarx for simple code
I created some little app that get args and use them to create report file.
but i got medium checkmarx.
this is my code (after i tried to fix the checkmarx with Math.min):
import reporter from 'cucumber-html-reporter';

/*******************************************************
 * Only for local run, this comes from the base docker
 */

const options = {
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    jsonFile: 'report/reportData.json',
    output: 'report/report.html',
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    scenarioTimestamp: false,
    launchReport: false,
    brandTitle: 'Puppeteer Tests Report',
    columnLayout: 1,
    metadata: {
        Name: 'Puppeteer Tests'
    }
};

const total = Math.min(parseInt(process.argv.length), 1000);
if(total < 0) {
    throw new Error('Invalid userInput');
}

// getting the IP
for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    const arg = process.argv[i];

    if (arg.includes('--ip')) {
        options.metadata.IP = process.argv[i + 1];
    }
}

reporter.generate(options);

and this is the checkmarx:
The application goes into a loop with total at base_ond_puppeteer_js\reporter.js in line 27. However, to determine the amount of iterations that this loop performs, the application relies on the user input argv at base_ond_puppeteer_js\reporter.js in line 21. Similarity ID: 954597347

and one more checkmarx for same line:
Method Math.min at line 21 of base_ond_puppeteer_js\reporter.js gets user input from element argv . This element’s value flows through the code without being validated, and is eventually used in a loop condition in for at line 27 of base_ond_puppeteer_js\reporter.js. This constitutes an Unchecked Input for Loop Condition. Similarity ID: 954683830

i tried a lot of things to validate the argv but nothing worked.
TNX a lot :)
